# Jupyterhub not running on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, jupyterhub

Been stuck in this issue for the past two days.

Followed the github link regarding this issue. Didn't worked.
https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub/issues/237

```
saimmehmood@saimmehmood-VirtualBox:~$ sudo jupyterhub
[sudo] password for saimmehmood: 
[I 2016-03-22 02:18:54.577 JupyterHub app:558] Loading cookie_secret from /home/saimmehmood/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[W 2016-03-22 02:18:54.865 JupyterHub app:292] 
Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.

[W 2016-03-22 02:18:54.893 JupyterHub app:685] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2016-03-22 02:18:54.900 JupyterHub app:686] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2016-03-22 02:18:54.906 JupyterHub app:712] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2016-03-22 02:18:55.016 JupyterHub app:1113] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[E 2016-03-22 02:18:55.055 JupyterHub app:855] Refusing to run JuptyterHub without SSL. If you are terminating SSL in another layer, pass --no-ssl to tell JupyterHub to allow the proxy to listen on HTTP.


saimmehmood@saimmehmood-VirtualBox:~$ sudo jupyterhub --no-ssl
[I 2016-03-22 02:19:12.896 JupyterHub app:558] Loading cookie_secret from /home/saimmehmood/jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[W 2016-03-22 02:19:13.046 JupyterHub app:292] 
Generating CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN. Restarting the Hub will require restarting the proxy.
Set CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN env or JupyterHub.proxy_auth_token config to avoid this message.

[W 2016-03-22 02:19:13.079 JupyterHub app:685] No admin users, admin interface will be unavailable.
[W 2016-03-22 02:19:13.080 JupyterHub app:686] Add any administrative users to `c.Authenticator.admin_users` in config.
[I 2016-03-22 02:19:13.080 JupyterHub app:712] Not using whitelist. Any authenticated user will be allowed.
[I 2016-03-22 02:19:13.149 JupyterHub app:1113] Hub API listening on http://127.0.0.1:8081/hub/
[W 2016-03-22 02:19:13.174 JupyterHub app:851] Running JupyterHub without SSL. There better be SSL termination happening somewhere else...
[I 2016-03-22 02:19:13.174 JupyterHub app:860] Starting proxy @ http://*:8000/
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
[C 2016-03-22 02:19:14.297 JupyterHub app:1119] Failed to start proxy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 1117, in start
    yield self.start_proxy()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 881, in start_proxy
    _check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/jupyterhub/app.py", line 877, in _check
    raise e
RuntimeError: Proxy failed to start with exit code 127
```

Kindly let me know any solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in this line

`/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory`

Either you don't have nodejs installed or it's not in `$PATH`. Note that nodejs/npm are required to run jupyterhub. It *looks* like you're running some linux distribution so you should just be able to run

`sudo apt-get install npm nodejs-legacy`

See [the JupyterHub GitHub page](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterhub) and the [docs](https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for more info.

Comment: Thank you Will! Surprising, how could I miss such a thing. :)